# Signing response using openSAML

Tags: java, xml, opensaml

I am attempting to implement SAML 2.0 by signing the response, instead of the Assertion. I have 3 existing vendors that accept my signature at the Assertion level, however a new vendor is requesting it at the protocol / response level. I have been Googling and debugging for about 8 hours, and cannot find a valid example of what I am doing wrong.  My code below shows clearly what I am doing, and the last 10 lines or so of it are the differences that I have implemented (within the if / else). Also, I noticed in my XML that my SignatureValue and DigestValue are both empty. Can anyone point me towards some clear documentation, or better yet, an example of a working response signature using openSAML? At this point, any help is appreciated.

```
Assertion assertion = OpenSamlHelper.CreateSamlAssertion(
            issuer.trim(), recipient.trim(), domain.trim(), subject.trim(),
            attributes);        


    //
    // Sign
    //
    Credential signingCredential = getSigningCredential(keystore, storetype, storepass, alias, keypass);

    Signature signature = (Signature) Configuration.getBuilderFactory()
                            .getBuilder(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME)
                            .buildObject(Signature.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);

    signature.setSigningCredential(signingCredential);
    signature.setSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA1);               
    signature.setCanonicalizationAlgorithm(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);



            SecurityConfiguration secConfiguration = Configuration.getGlobalSecurityConfiguration(); 
            NamedKeyInfoGeneratorManager namedKeyInfoGeneratorManager = secConfiguration.getKeyInfoGeneratorManager(); 
            KeyInfoGeneratorManager keyInfoGeneratorManager = namedKeyInfoGeneratorManager.getDefaultManager();
            KeyInfoGeneratorFactory keyInfoGeneratorFactory = keyInfoGeneratorManager.getFactory(signingCredential);
            KeyInfoGenerator keyInfoGenerator = keyInfoGeneratorFactory.newInstance();
            KeyInfo keyInfo = null;
            try {
                keyInfo = keyInfoGenerator.generate(signingCredential);
            } catch  (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            } 
            signature.setKeyInfo(keyInfo);

            String saml = "";
            try {
            MarshallerFactory marshallerFactory = Configuration.getMarshallerFactory();
    if (signatureType == SignatureType.Response) {
        response.setSignature(signature);
                    marshallerFactory.getMarshaller(response).marshall(response);
    }
    if (signatureType == SignatureType.Assertion) {
        assertion.setSignature(signature);
                    marshallerFactory.getMarshaller(assertion).marshall(assertion);
    }
        Signer.signObject(signature);
```

UPDATE: The XML I was getting with the above code did not include a signatureValue or Digest  Value, like below..

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#_651cc837-e890-46c7-9cf9-646ffd38aaad">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue/>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue/>
```

After moving the Signer.signObject(signature); to a point after the assertion was attached to the response, I receive the following XML..

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#_273e38e9-3b51-4845-8b8b-f0970e3e9bab">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>UlVtsjSAvtjOLMbw+HUX9n7FtxM=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
jM7GxZ77VBHuAatMXLx14s0ExOmmfDpBhCpF8OKV4F3C1BiRutM41aTH25yhgSn+6l4TkK6kEDbFOYI6isvJUhtdVgH4E1xJl0DFfvPJphTF096acvJrLPehpsFd2Ab6sARuV1sbg/gwNFzvlHJWgit5NxHNuFN1qcv3vuhvQ83fOfxxuyLyJrEjpqvbRzwWepHiuTVHlNObrUvjVxEc7AUKPtwTqGlA6y3SdzIDwjN/LsB1V6PWhiMZsbxJx3LUuk5UECOYmRhKQifZWdOdvHoWBq05J54I6RvAplNDTfRBr4AM+tfIz3OXpN6OpKdSC43HRg9LO9bXprui+4CvrQ==
</ds:SignatureValue>
```

Comment: I'm going to try to reproduce this tomorrow. What response are you trying to sign here? The above code sign the assertion right but not the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to sign and artifact response using this code, just switching the entityDescriptor to an artifactResponse and it worked fine.
https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/11/signing-with-opensaml.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:ArtifactResponse xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Version="2.0">
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>ZkE02ZnvIqyd+FcfL6PaXNI88Co=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>fDxfW06rbJEFu5nqmsGxwt6O53N8FWwmDOO0e3nUWh0in2TRYD9nj2927pnQZNL4Mk3KAcSWVETUuHX11XWL+MgcosfJd31TR0XEui/F+BbojQlXJRHfD2BfEO9cQCygFSyyOb9tE2FU5noqnx2b3vI5mToam3a135007mAN/t14Jm71EfvvCF9qL2wXI55R8uab0WGqXx1LYSrAjBZq455SH9AIQu+n8L+KaiOzfpjiL+h/5YJ/a+uyiLV6H06TsytowDTBSW67YW110fpoOsD5vgULrZOABmeK6NRZWpI8PK1M+/r6SO0DTEbUiSTYtHz9XBcqbnD9d7ZQ3oZpEQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>MIIDaTCCAlGgAwIBAgIEeL6vczANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBlMQswCQYDVQQGEwJOTzENMAsGA1UE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</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
</saml2p:ArtifactResponse>
```

Try to skip the KeyInfo part. Your not getting any marshalling errors?

Comment: I'm going to try what you suggested with the entityDescriptor, I'll post back once I've tested it. And no, I'm not getting any marshalling errors, in fact, the only noticeable issue is that the DigestValue and SignatureValue come back empty, and of course, that the vendor can't authenticate.

Comment: So after a few cups of coffee this morning, I looked through my code and realized I was trying to sign the response before adding the Assertion to it. This was my issue, and once I fixed the ordering of things, everything worked out. Thank you very much for the response, your code helped assure me that what I was doing was not completely wrong!

Comment: i dont understand, you tried to sign the artifactResponce before adding the artifact. That shouldn't make the response not signed. It would be invalid bud you should have a signature on it.

Comment: I updated the original question above with the before and after XML. The Signature area was there, but the SignatureValue and DigestValue were empty.

Comment: @Devon Does the original post now have the final working code?

Comment: @StefanRasmusson, can I get the full code for the above. I have also similar requirement.

Comment: I dont have anything specific to signing Responses but I do have a quite detailed blog in signing and verifying in OpenSAML. I thing that can easily fit to Response aswell. https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/11/verifying-signatures-with-opensaml.html. I also have the full code on github among other examples here. https://github.com/rasmusson/OpenSAML-sample-code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after I added

```
signature.setEntityCertificate(cert);
```

And

```
 KeyInfoGenerator keyInfoGeneratorFactory= keyInfoGeneratorFactory.newInstance();
  if (keyInfoGeneratorFactory instanceof X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory) {
                ((X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory) keyInfoGeneratorFactory).setEmitX509Digest(Boolean.TRUE);
                ((X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory) keyInfoGeneratorFactory).setEmitX509IssuerSerial(Boolean.FALSE);
                ((X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory) keyInfoGeneratorFactory).setEmitEntityCertificate(Boolean.FALSE);
                ((X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory) keyInfoGeneratorFactory).setEmitPublicKeyValue(Boolean.FALSE);
                ((X509KeyInfoGeneratorFactory) keyInfoGeneratorFactory).setX509DigestAlgorithmURI(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);}
```