# Create a credential object in java SAML

Tags: java, xml, saml, credentials, opensaml

I'm working on the sign SAML assertions. My code is the same as in this question:

[Signing response using openSAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368167/signing-response-using-opensaml)

I need to create the method `getSigningCredential()` to make the credential object. How can I create this `Credential` object?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, depending on where you stor your keys. Metadata, keystore or somewhere else.

I have a [blog post on this subject](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/03/getting-credentials-in-opensaml.html) and I discuss it further in my book [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html)

Basically you use one of the provided CredentialResolvers in OpenSAML

MetadataCredentialResolver
KeyStoreCredentialResolver
etc...

Comment: Thank you Stefan for your reply. I solved otherwise.